# Interactions in fixed-effects model of within individual differences in exposure from panel data

Tags: r, regression, interaction, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

**Background**

I am using a fixed-effects regression of 8 wave panel data to determine whether the relationship between water cover near to where someone lives and their health status (score of 0-100) is modified by by simultaneous changes in the wealth of the area they are living in. I want to obtain a completely "within-person" estimate of this potential effect modification. The most efficient way to do so is to "double-demean", that is demean wealth and water individually, and then demean their interaction (Giesselmann et al. 2020). This requires at least 3 data-points.

**Question**

I am unsure whether or not I have the data to answer using the model I propose, which will have an interaction. In my data changes in water and wealth are caused exclusively by individuals moving. Not many individuals move, and those that do only move once (more than 5k people). However, before and after moving we still record their health status (across all 8 waves). I am not interested in the effect of moving but in states of exposure. They are still experiencing exposure (albiet identical) to the same amount of water cover and wealth nearby across years, giving 8 observations per person. E.g. pre-move they have 4 waves reporting the same exposure to water and wealth, with different health status scores, then post move they have 4 waves with a different exposure to water and wealth with again different health status scores each wave.

I would like to follow a similar approach to interactions as Giesselmann et al. (2020) for a completely within-person analysis, would my data allow for this? E.g. as the trigger for the change in the exposure (moving) is simultaneous for both variables in the interaction, does this mean I violating fixed-effects assumption of exogeneity?

Thanks for your help in advance. Below is a simulated dataset and code in R which I hope can make the problem easier to understand. Apologies for the code length and packages, simulating the data structure was tricky.

**Code**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(simglm)
library(panelr)

### Simulating data, one move but health measured across multiple waves
sim_args <- list(
  formula = y ~ 1 + water + wealth + (1 | personid),
  reg_weights = c(50, 10, -5), #average effect (betas)
  fixed = list(water = list(var_type = 'continuous', 
                            mean = 0.3, 
                            sd = 0.08),
               wealth = list(var_type = 'continuous', 
                             mean = 0, 
                             sd = 0.4)),
  randomeffect = list(personid = list(variance = 4, 
                                      var_level = 2)), #variance between individuals
  sample_size = list(level1 = 2, level2 = 3000) #this is the responses (level 1) per number of individual (level 2)
)

fixefsimdat <- sim_args %>%
  simulate_fixed(data = NULL, .) %>%
  simulate_randomeffect(sim_args) %>%
  generate_response(sim_args)

fixefsimdat$waveid <- fixefsimdat$level1_id
minilist <- vector("list",length=3)
maxilist <- vector("list",length=3)
for (i in 1:3){
  min_i <- fixefsimdat[fixefsimdat$waveid==1,]
  min_i$fixed_outcome <- min_i$fixed_outcome+rnorm(nrow(min_i), sd=3)
  min_i$waveid <- min_i$waveid-i
  minilist[[i]] <- min_i
  max_i <- fixefsimdat[fixefsimdat$waveid==2,]
  max_i$fixed_outcome <- max_i$fixed_outcome+rnorm(nrow(max_i), sd=3)
  max_i$waveid <- max_i$waveid+i
  maxilist[[i]] <- max_i
}
allwavelist <- c(rev(minilist),list(fixefsimdat[fixefsimdat$waveid==1,],fixefsimdat[fixefsimdat$waveid==2,]),maxilist)

pplinsurvey <- max(do.call(rbind,minilist)$personid)
waveattrition <- pplinsurvey/20
waveremaining <- c(pplinsurvey,(pplinsurvey - cumsum(rep(waveattrition,length=7))))

waveids <- c(-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5)
fixefsimdat_forattrit <- fixefsimdat$personid
dataperwave <- vector("list",length=8)
for (i in 1:8){
  waveid <- waveids[i]
  waveattrition_i <- sample(x = unique(fixefsimdat_forattrit),
                        size = waveremaining[i])
  fixefsimdat_forattrit <- fixefsimdat_forattrit[fixefsimdat_forattrit %in% waveattrition_i]
  peopleinwave <- allwavelist[[i]]
  peopleinwave <- peopleinwave[peopleinwave$personid %in% fixefsimdat_forattrit,]
  dataperwave[[i]] <- peopleinwave
}

dataperwave_bind <- do.call(rbind,dataperwave)
summary(as.factor(dataperwave_bind$waveid)) #ordered correctly

### Modelling simulated data using a within person double de-mean interaction
dataperwave_bind_pan <- panel_data(dataperwave_bind, id = personid, wave = waveid) #panelr needs this format

panelmod <- wbm(fixed_outcome~ 
                water*wealth,
              model="within",
              data = dataperwave_bind_pan)
summary(panelmod)
```

**References**

Giesselmann, M., Schmidt-Catran, A.W., 2020. Interactions in Fixed Effects Regression Models. Sociol. Methods Res. 0049124120914934. https://doi.org/10.1177/0049124120914934